# Writing a dictionary to a file in python

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, io

I want to write a complex List of dictionaries to a file. Below is my list of dictionaries:

```
[
  {
    "Year": "2015",
    "Movies": {
      "type": "Horror",
      "Total Hours": "3",
      "Trimmed": 3000,
      "List": [
        {
          "date": "20/10/15",
          "time": "10:00:00",
          "type": "Horror",
          "text": "abcjsaadasd",
          "start": 00:00:00,
          "end": 02:59:13
          "Hero":"asfaf"
        },
        {
          "date": "22/10/15",
          "time": "11:00:00",
          "type": "Horror",
          "text": "sdvsdnsdfa",
          "start": 00:00:00,
          "end": 02:55:10,
          "Hero":"dsvsfs"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Year": "2016",
    "Movies": {
      "type": "Thriller",
      "Total Hours": "3",
      "Trimmed":100,
      "List":[]
    }
  }
]
```

I know how to write to a file in Python but I don't know how to parse this kind of complex list of dictionary.

Also I need to check for the `List` and If it is empty I should erase that dictionary`(Eg: The second dictionary present in the above data)`.

Please help me to solve this issue.Thanks a lot!

Comment: look at the JSON library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html, as python list/dict literal representations are compatible with JSON, you can simply write the JSON to a file and load it from there.

Comment: @Adam.Er8: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
# filter out all dicts with empty List
filtered_data = [d for d in data if d.get("Movies", {}).get("List")] 
# write the filtered data 
with open("output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(filtered_data, f) into a file
```

Comment: The filtered_data works the opposite way .It takes the empty List

Answer (score 2):

For something like that, I would use it to write it to a JSON file. You can do that like that

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(your_complex_dataset)
df.to_json('file_name.json')
```

Comment: Yeah but before doing that I need to traverse through the dictionary to get some particular data which I will append to a list. So for doing those operations I need to know how I can traverse through a dictionary like this

Comment: check then the `json` library which provides function `json.dump()`

Comment: @Sushanth why do you think so? I mean I do not understand why that is an overkill

Comment: Thanks Aleksander I will look for it . So after writing that data to json file I will be able to perform the operations using json.dump()   Right?

Comment: @keerthi007 to perform the operation on the JSON data you have to load the JSON file, I would personally use the `DataFrame` from `pandas` `import pandas as pd df = df = pd.read_json('file_name')` by that you will have your JSON file in a dataframe and you can easily execute operations with it.

Comment: @keerthi007 can you upvote my answer and accept it please? :))

Comment: Yeah sure mate!

Answer (score 1):

Want to write complex objects to file?  Then try to Pickle it.

(Above Answers are good but sharing another way)

Pickle is a way to serialize a python object and save to a file. Once you have done so, you de-serialize back when every you want it.

#### To Write

```
import pickle
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] # Instead of list, this can be you dict or so,..
with open('datafile.pickle', 'wb') as fh:
   pickle.dump(mylist, fh)
```

#### To Read

```
import pickle
pickle_off = open ("datafile.txt", "rb")
emp = pickle.load(pickle_off)
print(emp)
```

Link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python-pickling

As for the part of the validation empty list, you can use `len` function if its empty and do as required.